# Issue in header filter for select editor in latest tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

With the latest tabulator version, I'm facing the below issue in headerfilter for select editor.

I could see similar behavior in documentation (http://tabulator.info/examples/4.8?#filter-header):

I can't reset the header filter once selected, only option I have is to either select one of the params in filter.

This issue was not there in 4.6 version (http://tabulator.info/examples/4.6#filter)

Please help me on how I could overcome this behavior. I would need a reset or input like remove option in header filter for select editor with latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue and worked around it by adding

```
'':'-All-'
```

to the headerFilterParams object.  This should give you an "-All-" option that selects an empty string, effectively unsetting the filtering.

Comment: Thanks, but do you knw why is this dropped by default in latest version ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not.  4.8 is the first version I've used.